# Android Wear API breaks Play Services if app not installed

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

This is definitely some sort of bug, but I don't know where to file this, and I want to see if other developers have a workaround.

I made this weather app and both my dad and sister downloaded it. It seemed to work for a while. Then my dad got a new phone (Moto E from Republic Wireless). Oddly, it gave an error when the app started. (16 from Google Play Services). That means API is Unsupported.

I didn't try to access too many APIs.

```
gapi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

Then last week it stopped working on my sister's phone, giving the same error. This made much less sense. We have the same phone and same carrier. Why wasn't it working? I made sure she had the most recent version of the app. Basically everything was the same. I posted online. Other people got this error. I didn't.

Let me be clear. I updated the app about a month ago. I hadn't published any new code. In the meantime, the app stopped working on various devices and I couldn't figure out why.

After trying nearly everything to reproduce this bug, I finally figured it out. I uninstalled my Android Wear companion app, something other people never had. In doing so, I received this error. Google Play Services must've created some bug that doesn't fail gracefully.

As a workaround, I'm going to try this:

```
if(appInstalledOrNot("com.google.android.wearable.app")) {
        gapi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    } else {
        gapi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
```

Where the method checks if the package is installed.

This isn't a great hack, and one that was caused by a regression. Is this a decent solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Tips for Error Handling with Android Wear APIs blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/tips-for-error-handling-with-android.html):

> There are two ways that the [connect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#connect()) method can return ConnectionResult.API_UNAVAILABLE for wearable support with Google Play services:
>
> - When requesting Wearable.API on any device running Android 4.2 (API level 17) or earlier
> - When requesting Wearable.API when no Android Wear companion application or device is available

Therefore this is expected behavior. Also per the blog post:

> The best practice for developers is to implement two separate GoogleApiClient connections:
>
> - One connection for Android Wear support, and
> - A separate connection for all of the other APIs you need
>
> This will ensure that the functionality of your app will remain for all users, whether or not there is wearable support available on their devices, as well as on older legacy devices.

This means you can direct Wearable calls to a `GoogleApiClient` connected only to the `Wearable.API` (and ignore if it is not connected) and direct all other calls to a different `GoogleApiClient` (which has no dependency on Android Wear).

Comment: Okay, technically it may be implemented as intended, but it is annoying that they didn't originally have this and then implemented it all of a sudden. I couldn't really find documentation on this error either.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This has been the case since the blog post was released back in October 2013. Also, searching for `API_UNAVAILABLE` on developer.android.com brings up that blog post and the [Accessing Google APIs training page](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html#WearableApi) with the same note on use of the `Wearable.API`.

Comment: Then perhaps there was a bug in between my dev time in which I could do  it and they fixed it.